# Find and retrieve content from html text using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have the following html code (or at least I think it's html) that I am working on with BeautifulSoup on Python.

I have parsed the html using Beautiful soup correctly. What I would like to do next is to retrieve the content associated with the 'div' containing a certain data-label (for example, in the bottom part of the code, data-label="Relation"). In particular I would like to obtain a dictionary that has as key the text of the data-label, i.e. in my example "Relation", and as value the content of the same 'div', i.e. in my example the href "http://documenti.camera.it/apps/commonServices/getDocumento.ashx?sezione=bollettini=comunicato=17=2016=06=14=03=data.20160614.com03.bollettino.sede00020.tit00010.int00010=data.20160614.com03.bollettino.sede00020.tit00010.int00010#data.20160614.com03.bollettino.sede00020.tit00010.int00010"

I have tried several approaches but data-label, as far as I know, does not appear to be a valid attribute, so I am not sure how to handle this.

(Note that this is just an example, but I will have to do the same for thousands, if not millions, of these webpages, with this similar structure).

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

```html
<div id="directs">
  <label class="c1"><a data-comment="A human-readable name for the subject." data-label="label" href="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label">
    rdfs:<span>label</span>
    </a></label>
  <div class="c2 value ">
    <div class="toMultiLine ">
      <div class="fixed">
        <span class="dType">xsd:string</span> 
        intervento di Fabrizio CICCHITTO
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <label class="c1"><a data-comment="A name given to the resource." data-label="Title" href="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/title">
      dc:<span>title</span>
    </a></label>
  <div class="c2 value ">
    <div class="toMultiLine ">
      <div class="fixed">
        intervento di Fabrizio CICCHITTO
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <label class="c1"><a data-comment="" data-label="" href="http://lod.xdams.org/ontologies/ods/modified">
      ods:<span>modified</span>
    </a></label>
  <div class="c2 value ">
    <div class="toMultiLine ">
      <div class="fixed">
        <span class="dType">xsd:dateTime</span> 
        2016-07-05T12:26:02Z
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <label class="c1"><a data-comment="The subject is an instance of a class." data-label="type" href="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type">
      rdf:<span>type</span>
    </a></label>
  <div class="c2 value">
    <div class="toOneLine">
      <a class=" isLocal" href="http://dati.camera.it/ocd/intervento" title="&lt;http://dati.camera.it/ocd/intervento&gt;">
      ocd:intervento
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <label class="c1"><a data-comment="propriet generica utilizzata per puntare alla risorsa deputato in vari punti dell'ontologia" data-label="rierimento a deputato" href="http://dati.camera.it/ocd/rif_deputato">
      ocd:<span>rif_deputato</span>
    </a></label>
  <div class="c2 value">
    <div class="toOneLine">
      <a class=" isLocal" href="http://dati.camera.it/ocd/deputato.rdf/d15080_17" title="&lt;http://dati.camera.it/ocd/deputato.rdf/d15080_17&gt;">
      http://dati.camera.it/ocd/deputato.rdf/d15080_17
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <label class="c1"><a data-comment="A related resource." data-label="Relation" href="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/relation">
      dc:<span>relation</span>
    </a></label>
  <div class="c2 value">
    <div class="toOneLine">
      <a class=" " href="http://documenti.camera.it/apps/commonServices/getDocumento.ashx?sezione=bollettini=comunicato=17=2016=06=14=03=data.20160614.com03.bollettino.sede00020.tit00010.int00010=data.20160614.com03.bollettino.sede00020.tit00010.int00010#data.20160614.com03.bollettino.sede00020.tit00010.int00010"
        target="_blank" title="&lt;http://documenti.camera.it/apps/commonServices/getDocumento.ashx?sezione=bollettini=comunicato=17=2016=06=14=03=data.20160614.com03.bollettino.sede00020.tit00010.int00010=data.20160614.com03.bollettino.sede00020.tit00010.int00010#data.20160614.com03.bollettino.sede00020.tit00010.int00010&gt;">
         http://documenti.camera.it/apps/commonServices/getDocumento.ashx?sezione=bollettini=comunicato=17=2016=06=14=03=data.20160614.com03.bollettino.sede00020.tit00010.int00010=data.20160614.com03.bollettino.sede00020.tit00010.int00010#data.20160614.com03.bollettino.sede00020.tit00010.int00010
        </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the `data-labels` in one pass and the `div` content in another. Then, the results can be zipped together to create the dictionary:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import re
d = soup(content, 'html.parser').find('div', {'id':'directs'})
_labels = [i.a['data-label'] for i in d.find_all('label')]
_content = [i.text for i in d.find_all('div', {'class':re.compile('c2 value\s*')})]
result = dict(zip(_labels, _content))
```

Output:

```
{'label': '\n\n\nxsd:string \n        intervento di Fabrizio CICCHITTO\n      \n\n', 
 'Title': '\n\n\n        intervento di Fabrizio CICCHITTO\n      \n\n', 
 '': '\n\n\nxsd:dateTime \n        2016-07-05T12:26:02Z\n      \n\n', 
 'type': '\n\n\n      ocd:intervento\n      \n\n', 
 'rierimento a deputato': '\n\n\n      http://dati.camera.it/ocd/deputato.rdf/d15080_17\n      \n\n', 
  'Relation': '\n\n\n         http://documenti.camera.it/apps/commonServices/getDocumento.ashx?sezione=bollettini=comunicato=17=2016=06=14=03=data.20160614.com03.bollettino.sede00020.tit00010.int00010=data.20160614.com03.bollettino.sede00020.tit00010.int00010#data.20160614.com03.bollettino.sede00020.tit00010.int00010\n        \n\n'}
```

Comment: @mgiom Glad to help!